# c# initializer block property set a property without set

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here a class from the Xamarin:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Xamarin.Forms
{

    [ContentProperty("Children")]
    public abstract class Layout<T> : Layout, IViewContainer<T> where T : global::Xamarin.Forms.View
    {
        protected Layout();
        public IList<T> Children { get; }

        protected virtual void OnAdded(T view);
        protected virtual void OnRemoved(T view);
    }
}
```

As you can see the Chidren property does not have a set, but I am able to set the property using block initializer:

```
new StackLayout
{
     Children = { Foo, Bar }
}
```

This should be allowed ? If a inherit from this class how do I set the Children property on my constructor ?

Comment: @StephenKennedy What's shown in the top half isn't the definition of the class, but rather the public API of the class.  It's what VS shows you when looking at the definition of a class external to the solution.  It wouldn't be a compilable class definition in any C# version, including 6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062).  It's compiled into calls to `Children.Add()`.